# Spark dataframe writeStream forEach not writing all rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

My source of data is Kafka, and I read data from kafka using this way:

```
var df = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094")
    .option("subscribe", "raw_weather")
    .load()

df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)")
        .as[String]
        .select("value")
```

The `value` received will look like: `(725030:14732,2008,12,31,11,0.6,-6.7,1001.7,80,6.2,8,0.0,0.0)`. There are 8784 rows (24*366) passed to Kafka.

I'm trying to stream this data inside a DB2 database using a class that extends `org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]`. Here is how I try to write the data:

```
def writeToDb2(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame): Unit = {
    val writer = new JDBCSink(url , user , password)

    val query= df.writeStream
        .foreach(writer)
        .outputMode("append")
        .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(2000))
        .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
}
```

This is how my `JDBCSink` looks like:

```
class JDBCSink(url: String, user:String, pwd:String) extends org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]{
    val driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
    var connection:java.sql.Connection = _
    var statement:java.sql.Statement = _

    val schema = "SPARK"
    val rawTableName = "RAW_WEATHER_DATA"
    val dailyPrecipitationTable = "DAILY_PRECIPITATION_TABLE"

    def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long):Boolean = {
        Class.forName(driver)
        connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd)
        statement = connection.createStatement
        true
    }

    def process(valz: org.apache.spark.sql.Row): Unit = {
        val value = valz(0).toString.split(",")
        val stmt = s"INSERT INTO $schema.$rawTableName(wsid, year, month, day, hour, temperature, dewpoint, pressure, wind_direction, wind_speed, sky_condition, one_hour_precip, six_hour_precip) " +
            "VALUES (" +
            "'" + value(0) + "'," +
            value(1) + "," +
            value(2) + "," +
            value(3) + "," +
            value(4) + "," +
            value(5) + "," +
            value(6) + "," +
            value(7) + "," +
            value(8) + "," +
            value(9) + "," +
            value(10) + "," +
            value(11) + "," +
            value(12) + ")"
        println(value(1) + "," + value(2) + "," + value(3) + "," + value(4) + "," + value(11))

        statement.executeUpdate(stmt)
    }

    def close(errorOrNull:Throwable):Unit = {
        connection.close()
    }
}
```

Here's the thing, when I send the data to the stream, spark does not read all the lines. This became clear once I looked at the code where program tries to write. When I performed a `COUNT (*)` in my table, it does not write all 8784 rows in the table. In some iterations of the program, the number of rows written hovers around 7000, then sometimes 7900 etc., ie. it does not write all the rows.

What could be the reason behind it? I have followed the Structured Streaming Guidelines. Moreover, I have also tried to run using various other triggers but none have helped either.

Comment: seems like good for me. you dont have exception handling in process. have you find any exceptions in the logs? take sample of remining rows and try to insert the same data with your jdbc program. you may understand the real reason. i think they are bad records.

Comment: Hi, they're not bad records for sure. I could do map and reduce operations on my data source properly on another program. I also haven't found anything weird in the Spark Master logs

Comment: Do more debugging. Narrow down the issue. Count rows at each step and compare expectations to actuals.  Are you  compiling the insert statement per each row?

Comment: duplicates possibly?

Comment: No duplicates. But in any case spark should be able to read from the stream right? Spark does not read all the rows. And that's the issue. I should have made this clear. Sorry

Comment: @Sparker0i if you have already proved that the issue is between Spark and Kafka, in that Spark is not reading all the rows from the source, then do you still need the Db2 tag on your question (as it does not appear to be a database issue).

Comment: Removed the db2 tag